# Need help to convert nested array object of array object (2 level) to array of object (1 level) in ReactJS TypeScript

Tags: javascript

I got a issue when try to extract a 2 level nested array of object to 1 level array of object. I use React with TypeScript. This is my source array:

```
const sidebar = [
    {
      label: "label 1",
      children: [
        {
          label: "label 1.1",
          path: "/setting/roles",
          icon: "icon 1.1",
        },
        {
          label: "label 1.2",
          path: "/setting/employees",
          icon: "icon 1.2",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "label 2",
      path: "'/setting/departments'",
      icon: "icon 2",
    },
  ];
```

and below is my expected array:

```
const sidebarExpected = [
    {
      label: "label 1.1",
      path: "/setting/roles",
      icon: "icon 1.1",
    },
    {
      label: "label 1.2",
      path: "/setting/employees",
      icon: "icon 1.2",
    },
    {
      label: "label 2",
      path: "'/setting/departments'",
      icon: "icon 2",
    },
  ];
```

I use Yarn and prefer a solution that don't need to install new package (but if don't have any way, a solution with new package e.g. lodash is ok too). Below is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "product-hrm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "run-p -l lint:*",
    "lint:es": "eslint src/** --ext .ts,.tsx --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --config .prettierrc.json --write '**/*.tsx'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/joy": "^5.0.0-alpha.32",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.87",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.6",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.2.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "countries-and-timezones": "^3.3.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "history": "5",
    "i18next": "^21.6.16",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.0",
    "jotai": "^1.4.9",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bottom-scroll-listener": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-drag-drop-files": "^2.3.7",
    "react-dropzone": "^12.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.22.5",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.7",
    "react-mui-dropzone": "^4.0.6",
    "react-query": "^3.34.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@honkhonk/vite-plugin-svgr": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.10",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.8.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.8.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^1.6.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.7",
    "eslint": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^2.3.4",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "vite": "^2.7.2",
    "vite-plugin-components": "^0.13.3",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^3.3.17"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will flatten it regardless of how many levels it has.

It's a recursive solution. As long as you have children, it calls itself on those children. The `flatten` parameter is initialized as an empty array, but on recursive calls it will be updated with the nodes without children (because of the else where it pushes) -- having the parameter passed to the function will benefit of [tail recursive function](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_tail-calls.html#sec_tail-recursive-functions) (if tail call optimization is implemented by the browser)

```js
const flat = (array, flatten = []) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
    if (array[i].children) {
        flat(array[i].children, flatten);
    } else {
        flatten.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  return flatten;
}
```

Comment: woa thanks so much, it's really good solution and useful in another situation